# ¿Cómo hacer codo con codo las variables de las subcategorías de un gráfico con categorías?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Quiero crear un gráfico con variables categóricas que dejan de lado las subcategorías.

Por el momento lo intenté:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

data = {'SQuAD': [0.633884, 0.425138], 'SQuAD2.0': [0.4485605, 0.320649]}

index =["cosine","euclidean"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index = index)
```

Que da :

```
              SQuAD  SQuAD2.0
cosine     0.633884  0.448560
euclidean  0.425138  0.320649
```

Luego trato de mostrar las cuatro columnas que representan los valores de `cos` y `euclidiean` dependiente de su pertenencia a SQuAD y SQuAD2.0 como aqui :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces traé :

```
clarity_color_table = pd.crosstab(index=df.columns, 
                          columns=df.index)
clarity_color_table.plot(kind="bar", 
                 figsize=(5,5),
                 stacked=True)
```

Que da :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, por un lado, no se respetan los valores y, por otro, se pierde la segunda columna cada vez.
¿Cómo hacer que los resultados aparezcan uno al lado del otro?

Comment: @eyllanesc No quiero que las dos columnas `SQuAD` y `SQuAD2.0` se toquan sino que la columnas de `cosine` y `euclidean` segun sus valores.

Comment: la frase *¿Cómo hacer que los resultados aparezcan uno al lado del otro?* me trajo esa confusión. segun señalas tu quieres que los valores tomen sus *valores correctos*.

Comment: @eyllanesc me disculpe. Sí, y no 1, como aquí

Comment: podria mostrar una imagen de lo que desea obtener

Comment: @eyllanesc Claro. Acabo de agregarlo !

Comment: genial, ahora se entiende fácilmente tu problema :)

Comment: ¿tú quieres obtener lo siguiente? https://imgur.com/a/5nALxyx

Comment: @eyllanesc ¡Sí! ¡Exactamente!

Comment: solo usa `df.T.plot.bar()
plt.show()`, no es necesario `clarity_color_table`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82160/discussion-between-thepassenger-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es plotear la transpuesta del dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

data = {'SQuAD': [0.633884, 0.425138], 'SQuAD2.0': [0.4485605, 0.320649]}

index =["cosine","euclidean"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index = index)
df.T.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]